# Calculate angle between 3 vertices

Tags: python

I want to calculate angle between 3 vertices. In blender. When you measure the angle and move the one of the vertices, the angle still stays the same. I want to see angle changing while I move the point.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 7):

This might not be a great answer if you need Python code for something you are scripting, because it might be quite some digging to find what you need in the code, but if you only need to see it, MeasureIt add-on is a quick solution:

[image]