# Control angle between camera and object

Tags: camera

I have a scene with several objects. It is a geographical map from the [Shriveling world project](https://theworldisnotflat.github.io/shriveling_world). I want to control the angle between the camera and the geographical plane. I created a plane that is approximately aligned with the geo plane. I tested the [addon MeasureIt as in this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/234557/calculate-angle-between-3-vertices), but this does not work since the camera seems to possess no vertex.

My need is: I want to control the camera angle of view with this plane, with zero angle from above and, e.g., 45 deg from any position, north, south, east, west, etc.

[image: a shriveled Germany]

Comment: clear all of the transforms of the camera and place it at the origin. create an object that does have vertices, also at the origin and with all of its transforms clear.  Parent the camera to the object.  Now when you position the object, the camera will take the same location and rotation, so long as you don't move it independently.

Comment: While testing your solution, I discovered an approximative way with the built-in _Measure_ tool, using three points, the first on a limit of the 'geoplane', the second at its center and the third at the camera

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the built-in *Measure* tool:

1. In *Object* mode select the *Measure* tool from the toolbox in the left
2. Click on a part of the object
3. Click on the center of the camera
4. Make sure that the two extremities are snapped:

   - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Click</kbd> on the extremity
   - Move to the intended location
5. Click on the middle of the measure line and drag to a point in the center of the object (see image); this shows the angle

In my case, the desired angle was measured when the first point was located on the object in the same direction as where the camera is; this first point has to be adjusted if the camera moves

[image]